# Where are the rest of the Dwarves of Nidavellir?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, Eitri says to Thor:

> Three hundred dwarves lived **on this ring**. I thought if I did what he asked, they'd be safe. I made what he wanted: a device capable of harnessing the power of the stones. And he killed everyone anyway. All except me.

From the "on this ring" part, one might understand that he means there are more dwarves elsewhere. Is this correct, and if so, where do they live?

Answer (score 5):

In the MCU canon comic *Thor: The Dark World Prelude* Issue #1 we see the troll lords attacking the ***planet*** Nidavellir. Presumably either this was later retconned or Nidavellir refers to both the planet and the forge we see in *Avengers: Infinity War*.

[image: _Thor: The Dark World Prelude_ Issue #1 panel showing the planet Nidavellir]

Answer (score 4):

#### In the MCU, they are not mentioned, but in the comics, other dwarves live in Weirdworld

- [Dwarves of Weirdworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarves_(Marvel_Comics)):

> There are a race of dwarves that reside in Weirdworld. The Elf Tyndall of Klarn once lived with a warren of Dwarves who were besieged by the Night-Fangers. They sent him on a quest where Tyndall encountered the newly hatched Velanna.
>
> Tyndall and Velanna later met the dwarf thief Mud-Butt who later became their ally.

- [Dwarves of Asgard (Nidavellir)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Nidavellir)

The other dwarves are the Dwarves of Asgard (Nidavellir), which are the ones we see in the movies.

In the movies, Nidavellir is portrayed as a multi-ringed megastructure that orbits a dying neutron star, but in the comics, it can be seen as a whole planet.

[image: Nidavellir]

Comment: As far as I am aware Weirdworld has not been mentioned to exist in the MCU.

Comment: hmm... found something. Looks like Black Knight is tied to Weirdworld somehow. And we'll get a new movie with the Black Knight in 2020. So maybe the dwarves will be there too?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Maybe, that would be awesome.